# Scale screen size Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu

I installed Kubuntu but the display is going off the screen. I checked settings and there is no option for scaling the screen. Please help me out here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to check the OS display driver settings, but not monitor's settings?

I'd first check if the problem is actually in the monitor/display itself. Most displays have inbuilt settings on how the picture is scaled. If you had a previous system that just worked with the display, it might be that oddities in that system were fixed by tuning the display, and now the display is the culprit. See if you can reset positioning / size within the display's settings.