# How to get unstuck from unwanted screen magnification mode in Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kubuntu, display, screen

A few days ago, my display in *Kubuntu 18.04.1* suddenly was magnified as if, from that time onward, a virtual display has been kept in memory which is perhaps twice as large vertically and horizontally as my physical display.

The virtual display thus contains a magnified version of what I want on my physical display. My physical display then presents only perhaps one quarter of the virtual magnified display, depending on where my mouse pointer is.

For instance, when I move my mouse pointer to the left hand top corner of my physical display the left hand top ~1/4 section of the virtual (magnified) display will be displayed on my physical display.

I can still use my laptop this way but, as you probably can imagine, it is awkward.

I am writing the posting you are reading on this laptop. I have used *Kubuntu* for many years. Since my last installation of 18.04, perhaps about 6 months ago, it has been running acceptably on my old *System_76 Bonobo Extreme* laptop. It would seem that pressing some combination of keys, or something in settings, should get me out of this mode. Rebooting my laptop does not solve the problem.

I found a problem perhaps [similar to mine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087040/scale-screen-size-kubuntu-18-04) but no solution was offered.

How can I get unstuck from this unwanted screen magnification mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exit from magnified screen that moves with the mouse on Kubuntu 18.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087693/how-to-exit-from-magnified-screen-that-moves-with-the-mouse-on-kubuntu-18-10) I don't know why you ignored this suggestion on meta but it would seem to be the same issue.

Comment: Mark, I probably looked for help on AskUbuntu a number of years ago but I don't remember having posted a question before today.  (At 85 my memory is worse than earlier in my life.)  In any case I struggled today navigating the site.  Is the "suggestion on meta" what is presented at the top of this page immediately under my question?  I didn't see that until just now, about at the same time I read your question asking me whether it answered my question.  Thank you for correcting my grammar.   I am grateful to whoever made the "suggestion on meta".  It solved my frustrating problem.  Vim

Comment: Glad you got helped, this is the other question I was referring to: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19239/does-this-kubuntu-related-question-belong-to-ask-ubuntu-or-to-a-kde-forum